# Why are vectors portrayed as a sub space of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Typically I have seen all vector notation showing it as a sub space of $R^n$. Why not $Q$ or $Z$?

Comment: Many of the simpler applications of linear algebra are to areas of math that are naturally interested in real numbers, eg. calculus and analysis, so that is probably the most important example, and some theorems are only true over $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.  However, vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ are also important.  Over $\mathbb{Z}$ you can't divide by the scalars, so it's not a vector space.  Nonetheless there's an important notion of "module" which is more general than vector spaces, and those are studied over $\mathbb{Z}$.